# Mail encryption on Windows RT

Tags: email, encryption, gnupg, windows-rt

Is it somehow possible to use mail encryption preferably via GPG on Windows RT?

Since on a Windows RT Surface tablet you only have access to Windows Mail as an app in the store, there is no fancy Thunderbird, Enigmail or GPG4Win.
The only thing I stumbled upon while searching the web for this issue was "[digital IDs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-digital-IDs-to-sign-or-encrypt-Windows-Mail-messages)" by Microsoft, but I'm not so sure about that...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem with the Microsoft Surface RT is that it is based on the ARM processor so this is maybe why GPG won't work... The Surface RT is, IMHO, very poor.

Comment: Oh? So the processor's architecture is the problem? GPG won't work on ARM? Isn't GPG just software that can be ported?

Comment: Compiling GnuPG for Windows RT should not be a problem; but since Windows RT has pretty much no market share I wouldn't expect any integration or GUI applications. As Windows RT has been abandoned by Microsoft, don't expect anything to change in this regard.

Comment: Okay, so the conclusion is that there is no GPG on Windows RT unless I compile it by myself?
Same for other PGP related programs or S/MIME?